# Why does iperf results not change with traffic control change to outbound?

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, tc

I have been trying to change bandwidth between two ec2 instances using tc and outbound rules using HTB and TBF. I set these rules on on ec2 instance which acts as server and then test from another which acts as client. Nothing changes. If I do the same thing but link the interface to `ifb` interface so I can rate on inbound it works.

Why?

Surely all requests coming in have to go out in test so the rate would be affected to some extent. Does iperf only try and upload is that why I do not notice? If I had equal upload and download test would I see this? So if for every packet in I had to have a packet out? Is this not what we sort of do anyway since packets have to sent acknowledgements that they were received?

Answer (score 0):

`iperf` measures traffic from client to server. Usually traffic shaping works on outgoing traffic only. Thus you would have to configure traffic shaping on the client or  use a different measurement, i.e. download from the server.

`ifb` is the work-around for making `tc` available for incoming traffic. Makes less sense, though, as you cannot control the traffic that is coming to you.